# SendKeys not sending '(' and ')'

Tags: c#, streamreader, sendkeys

I want to make text file repeater with StreamReader of C#.
But some problem is appear...

Example)
** input word
"A"(;!)'B'

** Output word
"A";!'B'

I don't know why '(' and ')' is not apply.

I tried to change StreamReader parameter such as Encoding.Default, utf8, utf32.

But they are nor solve it

Please advice to me.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        stopflag = 0;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.  
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"target.txt", Encoding.Default);
        //System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"target.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
        //System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"target.txt", Encoding.UTF32);
        //System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"target.txt", Encoding.ASCII);

        SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //System.Console.WriteLine(line);
            SendKeys.Send(line);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1200);
            counter++;

            if (stopflag == 1)
                break;
        }

        file.Close();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
```

Comment: Assuming `"A"(;!)'B'` is the line in your file, I would suggest that `StreamReader` is working fine - otherwise software developers around the world would be experiencing pretty major problems. Please step through your code with the debugger and confirm that this line is _read_ correctly into the `line` variable. (Note that strings will appear escaped when you hover over the variable, so you should click the  to see the actual string).

Comment: Note that I've removed the `[cjk]` tag since it's not clear how that relates to your question - all of the characters you have provided fall within the ASCII character set.

Comment: Oh, I check it. string is : line "\"A\"(;!)'B'" string. So StreamReader is already work well. Problem is "SendKey" function. Can you tell me more advice about it?

Comment: @tjdnfka2001 Why are you using `SendKeys` anyways? Why not just set the text value of whatever control you're sending the keys to?

Comment: @D Stanley I want to make to control many Desktop PC with just 1 keyboard.
It is necessary for my blind students, they are can't writing well....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`SendKeys.Send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=netframework-4.8):

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to specify the plus sign, use "{+}". To specify brace characters, use "{{}" and "{}}". Brackets ([ ]) have no special meaning to SendKeys, but you must enclose them in braces. In other applications, brackets do have a special meaning that might be significant when dynamic data exchange (DDE) occurs.

So one option is to replace all parentheses with `"{(}"` and `"{)}"` in your string before calling the method. You might even create a generic method that wil escape *all* special characters.

Or just set the value of whatever control you're trying to send the keystrokes to and avoid `SendKeys` alltogether...